# Apply userform answers in IF statement

Tags: vba, if-statement, outlook, userform

I am trying to implement an IF statement to add different user answers (like sTitle & sSurename) to HTML body, subject, etc. The code always goes to the second option, no errors.

Also it looks like when I have an empty email I see the signature but when I update anything in Body the signature disappears.

```
Sub template()

    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strContact As String
    Dim strHTML As String

    Dim sType As String
    Dim sTitle As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sSurname As String
    Dim sExpirydate As String
    Dim sGender As String

    With UserForm1

        sType = .ComboBox1.Value
        sTitle = .ComboBox2.Value
        sName = .TextBox1.Value
        sSurname = .TextBox2.Value
        sExpirydate = .TextBox3.Value
        sGender = .ComboBox3.Value

    End With

    Set myItem = CreateItem(olMailItem)
    strHTML = myItem.HTMLBody

    With myItem
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

        If sType = "New" Then
            .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><b>Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & "</b> 111 the message text here.  </BODY></HTML>"
            .Subject = "New case"
        Else
            .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><b>Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & "</b> 222 the message text here.  </BODY></HTML>"
            .Subject = "Old case"
        End If  

        .OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
        .ReadReceiptRequested = True

    End With

    myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Userform:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

UserForm1.StartUpPosition = 2

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "New"
    .AddItem "Renewal"    
End With

With ComboBox2
    .AddItem "Mr"
    .AddItem "Miss"
    .AddItem "Mrs"
    .AddItem "Ms"
End With

With ComboBox3
    .AddItem "You"
    .AddItem "He"
    .AddItem "She" 
End With

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or ComboBox1 = "" Or ComboBox2 = "" Or ComboBox3 = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Fill in all Boxes")

        Exit Sub
    End If
    Unload Me

template
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the code until you get to the `If` statement, and then tell us what the value of sType is.  (P.S. [iif-function] is different to [if-statement], so I updated your tag.)

Comment: Oops - I mustn't have saved my tag edits - have done so now

Comment: I have updated previous post, and added Userfrom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your initialisation of `ComboBox1`, I think you are testing for the wrong values in your `If` statement.  Instead of testing for `"New"` you should probably be testing for `"Form1"`.

It also appears that you have a typo because you declare a variable called `sSurname` but then you use `sSurename`.  (A similar issue exists with `sExpirydate`.)  It is **highly** recommended that you include `Option Explicit` as the first line of every code module, which forces you to declare all your variables.  That way, typos such as this are trapped at compile time rather than at run time.

```
'...
sSurname = .TextBox2.Value
sExpirydate = .TextBox3.Value    
'...
'...
If sType = "Form1" Then
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><b>Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & "</b> 111 the message text here.  </BODY></HTML>"
    .Subject = "New case"
Else
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><b>Dear " & sTitle & " " & sSurname & "</b> 222 the message text here.  </BODY></HTML>"
    .Subject = "Old case"
End If
```

Comment: I have updated all issues(and clode in first post), Same result, all links are missing and after pressing ok button always goes to Else.

Comment: @folkstorm - That's a completely new issue - now it won't be working because you are unloading the form before running your `template` subroutine, so all the values the user has set have been lost.

Comment: You are right, I have replaced  Unload Me by UserForm1.Hide and works fine. Now I should be able to finish this macro. Thank you.